# jQuery cycle on "hover" start from image "0" again

Tags: jquery, cycle

I have a simple question. 
Based on this fiddle with jquery cycle plugin:
http://jsfiddle.net/Kz6Gk/353/

I want the slider to reset on mouseout so the next time when I  hover again on it,it will start from 1st image.

I tried many options like `destroy`, `reinit`, `goto`, `startingslide` but I am unable to make it work, it always resumes from the last slider before the last call of mouseout.
For example, I modified the last part of the code like this , It should work but no luck yet:

```
jQuery(function($){
    // Cycle plugin
    $('.slides').cycle({
        fx: 'none',
        speed: 1,
        timeout: 770
    }).cycle("pause");
    // Pause & play on hover
    $('.slideshow-block').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('.slides').addClass('active').cycle('resume');
    }, function(){
        $(this).find('.slides').removeClass('active').cycle('goto', 0).cycle('pause');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/Kz6Gk/922/)
JS:

```
$(function($){

    // Cycle plugin
function recycle()
{
$('.slides').cycle("destroy").cycle({
    fx:  'none',
    speed: 1,
    timeout: 700
});
}
    // Pause & play on hover
    $('.slideshow-block').hover(function(){
    recycle();
        $(this).find('.slides').addClass('active').cycle('resume');
    }, function(){
    recycle();
        $(this).find('.slides').removeClass('active').cycle('pause');
    });

});
```

Comment: thanks both, have some other small issues , it's ok if i ask here or i go downvote?

Answer (score 1):

you can re initialize the cycle by calling cycle(option) again

```
jQuery(function($){

var initCycle = function(){
// Cycle plugin
$('.slides').cycle({
    fx:     'none',
    speed:   1,
    timeout: 770
}).cycle("pause");
}

// Pause & play on hover
$('.slideshow-block').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.slides').addClass('active').cycle('resume');
}, 
//re initiate after lost hover
initCycle });

//initiate cycle after page load
initCycle();
});
```